# Is there a quick way to create an array of return codes from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have an array of objects from the `MyClass` class:

```
MyClass myClassArray[] = {
  new MyClass(0, 1),
  new MyClass(2, 3),
  new MyClass(4, 5),
  new MyClass(6, 7)
};
```

Here, the `MyClass` constructor fills in two fields, which we shall call `field1` and `field2`.  Suppose now that I want to fill in an array containing the value of `field1` from each object in `myClassArray` (so the array will contain the values `0, 2, 4, 6`).  The following does not work:

```
field1Array = myClassArray.getField1();
```

Is there a quick 1-line way to fill in the new array using return codes from methods belonging to objects in the original array?  Obviously, I can do this using a `for` loop, but I'd rather make use of the features of the language, if they exist.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He wants to get the numbers `0,2,4,6` without a loop

Comment: sadly java has very few features to make code shorter, im pretty sure there is nothing in the language that helps you there

Comment: You'd be saving just two lines! It'd look cool but probably run slow ('coz of reflection).

Comment: you could write the `for` version, of getting the array, as a method thereby making it _oneline_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there are no other language features than a plain old and simple `for` loop.

With Java 8 there may be lambda expressions and perhaps some helper method for `Collection` which will do what you want. But Java 8 is not yet released.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to loop unless you are using Java 8+ which adds [lambda expressions](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html) to the language, in which case you can map your array to a new array:

```
int[] field1Array = Arrays
                      .stream(myClassArray)
                      .mapToInt(MyClass::getField1)
                      .toArray();
```

This is admittedly a theoretical answer since Java 8 will not be officially released until Q1 next year.

Comment: can you explain it a bit?how do they propose to do it?

Comment: @boxed__l It creates a stream of MyClass objects taken from the original array, then applies a mapping function which, for each MyClass, returns `m.getField1()` and converts the result into an array.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, in Java, there is no way to call a method on every element of the array, apart from using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] field1 = new int[myClassArray.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < myClassArray.size(); i++){
    field1[i] = myClassArray[i].getField1();
}
```

Your approach has to use a loop (while, here for), because you can't run through an array without one. Sure you can handle each element of the array one by one. But this would be a nightmare for a fair size of elements in the array.

Comment: He just mentioned that he is able to use loops, that's not what he requires, OP don't want to use any loop.

Comment: @Azad I suggested the right way to handle OP's requirement. I added some explaination why he should use it.